# I want to upload a folder data into database and count tha number od .pdfs &.doc are present in C#

Tags: c#, database, upload, c#-3.0

I have a requirement likme i do have a bunch of folders and each folder contains some set of .pdf,.doc,.xls.I need to upload a folder at a time to database and read the folder data data.in database it'll be stored in the format of file type,file name,file size.I have to do this in C#.Plz some one help me urgently.Thanks in Advance...

Regards,
Snehasis

Answer (score 0):

How-to Guide for iterating through files and folders [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513869.aspx) could be a good starting point. The sample code described in the guide, iterates through folders recursively and save list of files inside any folder in `System.IO.FileInfo[]` array, using which you can get all your required information about a particular file such as name, type etc.. and then save it in database.